# Passing context to a tooltip template from "ngFor" elements

Tags: angular7, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to pass data to my ng-bootstrap tooltip template. Following this example https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/examples#tplwithcontext , I am now stuck at adding the `#t1="ngbTooltip"` part. Because my elements are created by iterating over an array, I cannot manually add the #t1 part.

This is my best try:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngbs-tooltip-dyn

When hovering over one of the "cell *" table cells, I want the tooltip to render the appropriate template with the cell's data from `tooltipData`. 
Any considerations and help are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so I have solved this, and posting this for reference.

The reason why I was struggling is that I was thinking that the content would be pulled dynamically. Opposed to that, the way it works is to render all the tooltips.

I have updated my Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngbs-tooltip-dyn for reference.

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking for a template-only solution but it seems there's none. So for now I'm doing it over the component's code too.